# how to find the ways of handling pointer difference between ptr and ->

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

what is the difference of pointers between and which is better in terms of memory management

```
void Loo(){ 
 Song* pSong = new Song(…);
 //…
 string s = pSong->duration;
}
```

and

```
void Hoo(){ 
 unique_ptr<Song> song2(new Song(…));
 //…
 string s = song2->duration;
}
```

Comment: better in terms of memory management is `Song song;`

Comment: Besides the possible memory leak in your first example, there should be no practical difference. With that said, as noted by others there doesn't seem to be a need for pointers at all here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you need to call `delete` yourself and make sure it happens on all program control paths.

That is easier said than done. It's tempting to write `delete pSong;` just before the closing brace of the function and be done with it. But what happens, say, if `string s = song2->duration` throws an exception? (Yes it's possible; for example if `song2->duration` is a type that has a conversion operator defined so it can be assigned to a `string`.)

With `std::unique_ptr`, `delete` will be called for you when it goes out of scope.

Although in this particular case `Song song(...);` may be more appropriate.

Comment: what about in terms of memory management what would you suggest

Comment: @FailedProgrammer I would suggest that you never use bare owning pointers, and avoid ever writing allocating `new` expressions as much as possible. Also avoid using dynamic memory when unnecessary.